# Split InformationText into two columns without duplicates or NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to display two columns from one column called InformationText. This column has my website content and also my Entry requirements which are separated by a column called CourseInformationID, WebContent being '1' & EntryRequirements being '8'. I have split the column into two sub queries but I am receiving error Msg 512! I have been looking into forums and all sorts trying to find a fix with no luck. Here is the code:

```sql
        DECLARE 
    
    @DAY VARCHAR (10) = ' Day(s)',
    @Week VARCHAR (10) = ' Week(s)',
    @Year VARCHAR (10) = ' Year(s)'
    
    
    
    
    SELECT DISTINCT
    COALESCE (O.QualID,'') QualID,
    
    CASE WHEN LEN(O.Code) <= 9 THEN  LEFT (O.Code,5)
    ELSE LEFT (O.Code,8)
    END AS CourseCode,
    
    
    CASE WHEN LEN(O.Code) <= 9 THEN SUBSTRING(O.Code,7,LEN(O.Code)-6)
    ELSE SUBSTRING(O.Code,9,LEN(O.Code)-6) --Splits the Offering code into Course/Occurence code, Program/Course Levels. 
    END AS OccurenceCode,
    
    
    
    CASE 
    WHEN (O.Name LIKE '%ACCESS%') THEN 'Adult - Access to Higher Education'
    
    WHEN (O.Name LIKE '%ESOL%') THEN 'ESOL'
    
    WHEN (O.Code LIKE '%-F2%') THEN 'Community Learning'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%AAT%') OR (CL.Name LIKE '%BUSINESS%') THEN  'Business & Accounting'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Beauty%') OR (CL.Name LIKE '%Hair%') THEN 'Hair & Beauty'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Functional Skills%') OR (CL.Name LIKE '%GCSE%') THEN 'Maths & English'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Photography%') OR (CL.Name LIKE '%Graphics%') OR (CL.Name LIKE '%Media%') THEN 'Digital Media'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Sports%') THEN 'Sports'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Public Services%') THEN 'Public Services'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%ICT%') THEN 'ICT Technology & Computing'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Animal Care%') THEN 'Animal Studies'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%ICT%') THEN 'ICT Technology & Computing'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Childcare%' OR CL.Name LIKE '%Teaching%') THEN 'Teacher Education'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Hospitality & Catering%') OR (CL.Name LIKE '%Bus%')THEN 'Business & Accounting'  
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Engineering%') OR (CL.Name LIKE '%Enviromental%') OR (CL.Name LIKE '%Sustainability%') OR (CL.Name LIKE '%LB Engineering Centre%') THEN 'Engineering' 
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Construction%') THEN 'Construction' 
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Motor Vehicle%') THEN 'Motor Vehicle' 
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Science%') THEN 'Science'
    
    WHEN (CL.Name LIKE '%Pathways%') THEN 'Pathways' 
    
    WHEN (S.Description LIKE '%Distance Learning%') THEN 'Distance & Online Learning'
    
    WHEN (S.Description LIKE '%Community%') OR (S.Description LIKE '%School%') OR (S.Description LIKE '%Farm%') OR (S.Description LIKE '%Stopsley%') THEN 'Community Learning'
    
    -- HE COURSES(LO6)
    WHEN (O.Name LIKE '%PCE%') OR (O.Name LIKE '%PGCE%') THEN 'Teacher Education'
    
    WHEN (O.Name LIKE '%Child%') THEN 'ChildCare'
    
    WHEN (O.Name LIKE '%Health%' OR O.Name LIKE 'Disability') THEN 'Health & Social Care'
    
    WHEN (O.Name LIKE '%Leadership%' OR O.Name LIKE '%Management%') THEN 'Leadership & Management'
    
    WHEN (O.Name LIKE '%SSS%') THEN 'SSS Birmingham & Manchester Based'
    
    WHEN (O.Name LIKE '%Business%') THEN 'Business & Accounting'
    
    WHEN (O.Name LIKE '%Computing%') THEN 'Technology & Computing'
    END AS SubjectTab,   
    
    
    
    vCLI.Level1Code LearningArea,
    COALESCE (LA.NOTIONAL_NVQ_LEVEL_CODE, '') OfferingLevel, 
    O.Name AS OfferingName,
    
    
    (SELECT vCID.InformationText 
    WHERE vCID.CourseInformationTypeID = '1') AS WebContent
    
    ,
    (SELECT vCID.InformationText 
    WHERE vCID.CourseInformationTypeID = '8') AS EntryRequirements 
    ,
    vCID.CourseInformationTypeID,
    
    AB.Name AwardingBody,
    
    FORMAT(O.StartDate,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS StartDate ,
    FORMAT(O.EndDate,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS EndDate,
    
    CASE 
    WHEN (O.NumberOfWeeks BETWEEN '35' AND '69') THEN CONCAT(1,@Year)
    WHEN (O.NumberOfWeeks BETWEEN '70' AND '155') THEN CONCAT(2,@Year)
    WHEN (O.NumberOfWeeks >= '156') THEN CONCAT(3,@Year)
    WHEN (O.NumberOfWeeks BETWEEN '0' AND '34') THEN CONCAT(o.NumberOfWeeks,@Week)
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, O.StartDate, O.EndDate) BETWEEN '0' AND '7' THEN CONCAT(DATEDIFF(DAY, O.StartDate, O.EndDate),@DAY)
    END AS Duration, 
    
    S.Description AS Venue,
    
    COALESCE (FMAF.DLF_Fee_LR_1618,0) AS Fee1618,FMAF.DLF_Fee_LR_Adult AS 'Fee19+','£' + COALESCE (CAST (vOS.Fee1 AS char(136)),'0.00') FullCost,
    
    CASE 
    WHEN LEN (O.Code) <=9 THEN '16-18'
    WHEN (LA.NOTIONAL_NVQ_LEVEL_CODE >= '4') AND (vCLI.Level1Code = 'L06') THEN 'HE'
    ELSE 'Adult'
    END AS Category, 
    
    --CITy.Description AS Content,
    O.Code AS OfferingCode,
    O.UserDefined1 AS Link
    
    FROM
    Offering O 
    
    LEFT JOIN AwardingBody AB
    ON O.AwardingBodyID = AB.AwardingBodyID
    
    LEFT JOIN vOfferingStats vOS
    ON O.OfferingID = vOS.OfferingID
    
    LEFT JOIN vPR_FundMethodlogy_AssumedFee FMAF
    ON O.OfferingID = FMAF.OfferingID
    
    LEFT JOIN Site S
    ON O.SiteID = S.SiteID 
    
    INNER JOIN vCourseInformationDetail vCID
    ON O.OfferingID = vCID.OfferingID
    
    LEFT JOIN CollegeLevel CL 
    ON O.SID = CL.SID 
    
    LEFT JOIN vCollegeLevel_Info vCLI
    ON  O.SID = vCLI.SID 
    
    LEFT JOIN Learning_Aim LA
    ON O.QualID = LA.LEARNING_AIM_REF 
    
    WHERE 
    WebSiteAvailabilityID = '2' 
    AND GETDATE() <= DATEADD(DAY,42, O.StartDate) 
    AND O.Name NOT LIKE '%Cancelled%' 
    AND O.Name NOT LIKE '%School Link%' 
    AND O.Name NOT LIKE '%Amazon%' 
    AND O.Name NOT LIKE '%Apprentice%'
    --AND O.Code NOT LIKE '%-%'
    --AND O.Code NOT LIKE '%/%'
```

1st sample table
What I am getting now!

| CousreCode | OccurenceCode | WebContent | EntryRequirements | CourseInformationTypeID | OfferingCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2301 | 22 | NULL | You should have 4 GCSE grades 9-2 or A* | 8 | 23201 22 |
| 2301 | 22 | class=MsoNormal style="BACKGROUND:... | NULL | 1 | 23201 22 |

2nd Sample table
WOuld like it like this, where there is NO null values and NO duplicates!

| CousreCode | OccurenceCode | WebContent | EntryRequirements | CourseInformationTypeID | OfferingCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2301 | 22 | class=MsoNormal style="BACKGROUND:... | You should have 4 GCSE grades 9-2 or A* | 8 | 23201 22 |
| 2302 | 22 | class=MsoNormal style="BACKGROUND:... | You should have 4 GCSE grades 9-2 or A* | 1 | 23202 22 |

Comment: Is this part of a larger query? If not, why are you queries in brackets (making them subqueries)?

Comment: Yes its part of a larger query

Comment: Those queries don't really make sense either. Why are checking whether the value of `CourseInformationTypeID` from the table `vCourseInformationDetail` has a value of `CourseInformationTypeID` from the table `vCourseInformationDetail`? Why not just have `WHERE CourseInformationTypeID = 1` and do away with the `IN`?

Comment: So what about the error don't you understand? Those subqueries are returning *multiple* values, and you are not allowed to have said subqueries return multiple values in the context they are being used. The error is explicitly telling you both the problem and the why.

Comment: Because then it creates a row for 1 and a row for 8, duplicating and leaving Null values

Comment: I think you need to show us the larger query here, and explain your goal(s).

Comment: you have to decide what to do with multiple InformationText  , you ca STUFF it for exaple. but as row, you need to join it as another table and use the InformationText  in the select

Comment: You first subquery could simply be rewritten as `(SELECT InformationText FROM vCourseInformationDetail WHERE CourseInformationTypeID = '1')` and it would give the *same* results (and be more performant). (Note, it would still likely error, but we don't have an enough information to provide an answer).

Comment: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/t1O - The whole query, and yes that does show the same error. 

My goals are to have the entry requirements in one column and web content in another each offering needs an entry requirement and web content without null values or duplicates offerings. Sorry I am new to SQL and I am trying my best to understand this. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: What is that link for, @AnthonyKamau ? (I am also not clicking it, as I don't recognise the domain). If information is important top your question, use the [edit] feature.

Comment: I tired to edit the post but there was too many errors, so I just copy n pasted into an editor and shared the link.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by there were too many errors, but you still need to [edit]your question and provide us with representative code for what you actually have and your goals. Sample data (in a consumable format) and expected results (not as an image) will also help us help you. If you don't put the information in the question, we can't help you.

Comment: Okay, give me a minute while I figure this out.

Comment: @Larnu I have shared the code and some sample outputs that hopefully explains my query better.

Comment: That query looks significantly overly complicated; why all those `LEFT JOIN`s? As far as I can tell, half of those tables you *never* use in the `SELECT` or` WHERE` so why are they there? Why multiple references to `vCourseInformationDetail` (both in the `JOIN` and subqueries)?

Comment: The following tables with aliases are all `LEFT JOIN`ed and are **never** referenced (or are, but the column is not qualified): `Enrolment EMT`, `KISCourse KISC`, `ModeOfAttendance MOA`, `vOfferingFee vOF`  and `LinkedOffering LO`. In addition, `vCourseInformationDetail vCID` is `INNER JOIN`ed to and never referenced outside it's `JOIN`. Why are *any* of those tables `JOIN`ed to?

Comment: Your right... To be honest, they were there through trial and error. I have removed the idle joins. Although, vCourseInformationDetail vCID has been inner joined for the sub queries  vCID.vCourseInformationTypedID, vCID.InformationText

Comment: Those subqueries don't reference the table aliased as `vCID` at all, @AnthonyKamau , they reference their *own instance* of `vCourseInformationDetail` that isn't aliased.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Larnu, code looks a little cleaner( a little) haha. Do you have any idea on how to make the two columns WebContent & EntryRequirements to look like the second sample table I have provided uptop please?

Answer (score 0):

```
left join (
  SELECT 
    vCID.InformationText, 
    offeringid 
  FROM 
    vCourseInformationDetail vCID 
  WHERE 
    (
      vCID.InformationText is not null 
      AND vCID.CourseInformationTypeID = '1'
    )
) as webcont on webcont.OfferingID = o.OfferingID 

left join (
  SELECT 
    vCID.InformationText, 
    offeringid 
  FROM 
    vCourseInformationDetail vCID 
  WHERE 
    (
      vCID.InformationText is not null 
      AND vCID.CourseInformationTypeID = '8'
    )
) as Entreq on entreq.OfferingID = o.OfferingID
```

SOLVED